# Was bedeutet "auf und abseits"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Was bedeutet "auf und abseits" z. B. in dem Satz: *Du liebst Touren auf und abseits der Piste?* oder *Bob-Geschichten auf und abseits der Eisbahn*?

Der erste Satz kommt aus einer Produktbeschreibung von Skistöcken.

Bedeutet das soviel wie "auf und außer"? Aber wie kann man außer der Piste Ski fahren? Hat dieser Ausdruck vielleicht noch eine andere Bedeutung?

Comment: Beziehen sich "Bob-Geschichten" auf ein Buch?

Comment: Nein, es geht um den Bobsport.

Comment: Entschuldigung, schlecht gefragt: Woher kommt das Zitat mit den "Bob-Geschichten"? Im Gegensatz zu den Skistöcken kann man mit einem Bob schlecht außerhalb eines Eiskanals fahren. Also muss das hier eine übertragene Bedeutung haben.

Comment: Das Zitat kommt aus dieser Sendung: http://www.ardmediathek.de/tv/Sportschau/Bob-Geschichten-auf-und-abseits-der-Eisb/Das-Erste/Video?bcastId=53524&documentId=40742224

Comment: This is no fixed phrase and it's quite difficult to imagine another useful application for it.

Answer (score 3):

"Abseits der Piste" bedeutet "neben der Piste" oder "außerhalb der Piste" (bzw. jeweils "Eisbahn"). Skipisten werden üblicherweise speziell präpariert, um dort Ski fahren zu können. Neben den präparierten Pisten gibt es dann beispielsweise Tiefschneebereiche, die ebenfalls befahren werden können.

"Auf der Piste" bedeutet dann Fahren auf der präparierten Piste.
"Abseits der Piste" bedeutet dann Fahren neben der präparierten Piste, im Tiefschnee und ähnliches.

"Bob-Geschichten auf der Eisbahn" sind Geschichten zum Bob-Sport.
"Bob-Geschichten abseits der Eisbahn" ist übertragen zu sehen und meint Geschichten ohne direkten Bezug zu einem sportlichen Wettkampf.